# I am your cup of coffee - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am your cup of coffee
>   Applicable for anyone
>   I am very objective
>   I came from the sun
>
> After drinking me you'll be very active
>   You can take me anywhere
>   There's no garbage with me
>   Simplicity is so fair

*In order to be accepted, you must explain **EVERY** line. Every line has a meaning!*

Comment: `What am I?` "Your cup of coffee! Jeez, that wasn't too hard..." or so he thought.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> **Java**.

I am your cup of coffee

> The Java logo is a cup of coffee. Also, java is a type of coffee.

Applicable for anyone

> The Java Virtual Machine is available on a wide range of platforms.

I am very objective

> In Java, objects are king. In earlier implementations of the language, there were no primitive data types, and literally *everything*, including integers, was an object.

I came from the sun

> Java is a product of Sun Microsystems, although nowadays it's owned by Oracle.

After drinking me you'll be very active

> After drinking java the coffee, you'll be on high alert for a while.

**Edit:**

> and one of the *intents* of Java (1.2.4 in [this document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/intro-141325.html)) was that people who used it would have high performance.

You can take me anywhere

> As above, since Java is available on so many platforms, including mobile platforms (in fact, it's the primary language used to program for the Android operating system), you can literally take it anywhere you go.

There's no garbage with me

> Java has automatic garbage collection, unlike languages with completely manual memory management like C.

Simplicity is so fair

> I... honestly can't explain this one. Unless you think Java is a very simple and fair language, in which case my bias from working with it for a year in CS class is going to kick in and say that that last line is patently false.

**Edit:**

> Apparently the answer is that, again, one of the *intents* of Java (1.2.1 [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/intro-141325.html)) was that the language would be simple and familiar, even if in practice it really isn't.

Comment: *After drinking me you'll be very active* You got this one wrong.

Comment: Hmm? You mean it's not referring to the fact that caffeine is a stimulant?

Comment: It all links to the language itself.

Comment: How do you _drink_ a programming language?

Comment: The coffee indicates a "thinking in progress" pause cursor which make the program (interaction) inactive. Afterwards, it's "active" again. At least that would be my line.

Comment: @JoeZ. Still worth using spoiler tags, I think... (For all the "new" users to come.)

Comment: @Joe Z. I think you're taking that too literally

Comment: @BmyGuest As a rule, I don't use spoiler tags on my answers, and don't really appreciate it when people try to edit them in afterwards.

Comment: (There are some cases where I will spoiler an answer if there's no thought process to it, or spoiler some explanation to a bare answer.)

Comment: @warspyking: What is the link, then? I maintain that my answer is plausible enough, so if you could present your canonical one, it would be appreciated.

Comment: This was one of the 5 primary goals of Java: 'It must execute with "high performance"'

Comment: That... doesn't really follow from "you'll be very active".

Comment: Is this solved, then? If Joe says that it "executes with 'high performance'", then he's correctly answered "After drinking me you'll be very active"? I get the feeling we're beginning to veer into subjectivity at this point, both in regard to what's an acceptable answer, and in personal opinions on Java.

Comment: If you're active, if performing more efficiently than if you are not.

Comment: @itrieddacrab No, the last line is still there. Plus this is nothing subjective, it had to do with 1 of the **goals** of Java. (*Hint*; This comment helps you solve the last line)

Comment: So, I've edited my answer. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 1):

My alternative answer is

> Solar Heat

I'm your cup of coffee

> I'm hot (or warm) like your cup of coffee

Applicable for anyone

> Everyone feels me the same way

I am very objective

> I provide heat and warmth the same way to everyone

I came from the sun

> Literally

After drinking me you'll be very active

> A warm sun can stimulate you to be active

You can take me anywhere

> I'm available in all parts of the world

There's no garbage with me

> I'm a clean energy produced from fission with no garbage or waster

Simplicity is so fair

> You don't need to do anything to get (or feel) me. I'm simply available
>  to you

Answer (score 0):

Well I already read the answer, so there's no point in explaining my solution, but I think I can explain the line

> After drinking me you'll be very active

I think it means:

> "to drink sth. in", which means to figuratively absorb something, because you like it so much. For example, if you "drink in" a book then you read the whole thing in one sitting, because you find it that fascinating. And I think it's the same with Java. If you're eagerly learning everything about Java, because you like the language that much, you will be very active in working with it, because you know how to use it.

I hope i could explain my opinion it well enough.

Comment: what are you trying to say?